# Use FTP as a Virtual Directory in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ftp

Can I add a FTP Connection as a Virtual Directory in `IIS`?

What I need to do is I need to load some images from FTP Connection and my code as below.

```
        string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/temp2"));

    List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());


    foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
    {
        images.Add(String.Format("temp2{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFile)));
    }

    RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
    RepeaterImages.DataBind();
```

Temp2 should be my virtual folder.

Comment: Unsure if I understood. If your app has  file read/write permissions, you can use [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to copy, move, etc. (no need to FTP)?

Comment: I'm using FTP in a different server and what i need to do is i need to use a repeater and display images in ftp